# Change from synchronous to Asynchronous

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

Here i use `GET` method to fetch data from one Url and display the data in table view.I used `synchronous` to get data to display.

**Needed:**

I need to change this code to Asynchronous to display same data in table view.Here i just use my console to display data.

**Here my code:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self getdata];
}

-(NSString*)sha256HashFor:(NSString*)input
{
    const char* str = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA256(str, strlen(str), result);

    NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
    for(int i = 0; i<CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
    }
    return ret;
}

-(void)getdata {

    NSString *userName = @"user@gmail.com";
    NSString *password = @"passer";
    //encoding
    NSData *Data = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64String = [Data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

    base64String=[self sha256HashFor: base64String];

    NSString *urlString = @"https://api.exampleurl/user23/doc";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", userName, base64String];
    NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
    [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", str);

  }
```

- In this code i used base64 and shaa256 encoding.
- Can any one help me to do with Asynchronous. I don't know how to do
  that. please help me with code explain.
  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try? Try something. What did you try? What did it do wrong?

Comment: No i havent any idea to convert this synchronous to asynchronous. I am new to ios and this is my first app. so only this confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For making Asynchronous http request you can use :

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:httpRequest queue:[AppDelegate connectionQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    ....
}];
```

or you can implement `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` protocol

### Updated Answer :

1. First create a connection queue in app delegate file

   `+ (NSOperationQueue *)connectionQueue
    {
       dispatch_once(&once, ^{
           connectionQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
           [connectionQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:2];
           [connectionQueue setName:@"com.XYZ.connectionqueue"];
       });
       return connectionQueue;
   }`

#### Here is updated getData Method :

```
-(void)getdata {

NSString *userName = @"user@gmail.com";
NSString *password = @"passer";
//encoding
NSData *Data = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *base64String = [Data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

base64String=[self sha256HashFor: base64String];

NSString *urlString = @"https://api.exampleurl/user23/doc";

NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", userName, base64String];
NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
[request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

__block NSString *str;

```
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:httpRequest queue:[AppDelegate connectionQueue]completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];}];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But i am new to ios. does i need to insert this line at any replacement of my code

Comment: yes you just need to replace `NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];` with 
`[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:httpRequest queue:[AppDelegate connectionQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    ....
}];`